# Compare a permutation to list of words - Python

Tags: python, string, set, permutation

I'm trying to compare the output of a permutation of a string to a txt with pretty much every word in the dictionary. The function itself is an anagram solver.

The function takes word as a parameter. Here's basically what I have

```
def anagram(word):
{c for c in permutations(word,len(word))}
```

this output will give me a set of possible combinations of word.

If word = dog, the output will be:

```
[{'d','g','g'},{'g','o','d'}
```

plus the other 6 or so combinations.

I want to compare the result of this permutation to a list of words and then return the word(s) which are anagrams of the original word.

So

```
if result (god or dog or dgo or gdo...) is in word_list:
return result
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Sorry I didn't explicitly say that the word list had already been imported in as a set/list.

The code for that is:

```
def load_words():
name = 'words.2-10.txt'
if isfile(name):
    all_words = [ l.rstrip() for l in open(name, 'r') ]
    as_lists = {}
    for size in range(2, 11):
         as_lists[size] = [ word for word in all_words if len(word) == size ]
    as_sets = { size : (set(words) if words else None) for size, words in as_lists.iteritems() }
    return as_lists, as_sets
return None, None
```

word_lists, word_sets = load_words()

Apologies!

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to write a small program that saves your wordlists filtered by size to separate files, eg word.3.txt contains only 3 letter words, etc. Especially if you intend to run your anagram generator with a single input argument. Of course, if a typical run of your program creates a bunch of anagrams of different sizes then you might as well load your entire dictionary.

Comment: It will only run once. There are 285375 words in the dictionary starting with aa, ending with some z word like 10 letters wrong.

Comment: Searching on subsets filtered by size will be noticeably faster than searching the entire dictionary - I just did a quick test and doing a search for 50000 random 8 letter words took around 2/3 the time of 50000 random words from my entire dictionary of 44785 words. OTOH, Python set creation and searching is rather fast (much faster than doing it by binary search of a sorted list, even for a list this size) although doing the filtering operation each time you run the program adds some overhead.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get all the words from the file, and form a set using set comprehension, like this

```
with open("strings.txt") as strings_file:
    words = {line.strip() for line in strings_file}
```

And then, when you generate the permutations, just join them with `"".join`, like this

```
def anagram(word):
    return {"".join(c) for c in permutations(word, len(word))}
```

and then you can simply do set intersection operation, like this

```
print words & anagram("dog")
```

Now, you can use the same set of `words` to compare against any number of permutations, like this

```
print words & anagram("cabbage")
print words & anagram("Jon")
print words & anagram("Ffisegydd")
```

Comment: The word list we have is a dictionary literal and I can't do intersect on dict literals.

This is the code I have that imports it:
`def load_words():
    name = 'words.2-10.txt'
    if isfile(name):
        all_words = [ l.rstrip() for l in open(name, 'r') ]
        as_lists = {}
        for size in range(2, 11):
             as_lists[size] = [ word for word in all_words if len(word) == size ]
        as_sets = { size : (set(words) if words else None) for size, words in as_lists.iteritems() }
        return as_lists, as_sets
    return None, None

word_lists, word_sets = load_words()
`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include all relevant information!

Comment: Sorry! I thought it wouldn't make a difference!

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def anagram(word):
    for w in itertools.permutations(word):
        yield ''.join(w)

def main():
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    listOfWords = ['some', 'list', 'of', 'words']
    for w in anagram(word):
        if w in listOfWords:
            print(w, 'is in the list')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with python [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). If you need a more efficient way than sets you should look into generators (yield) and the filte method.

```
from itertools import permutations

word_list = set(["god", "dog", "bla"])

def anagram(word):
    perm = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(word)]
    return set(perm)

dog = anagram("dog")
print word_list.intersection(dog)
```